# TestRestTemplate fails on postForEntity after adding spring security configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have some strange issue with my old tests after adding spring security configuration.

So, let's start from beginning to my already existing project I have added Spring Security and `JWT Filter`. The reason for that is that every request from UI, we are expecting JWT token and what we want to allow only users with given roles to access given endpoints.

**Configuration code:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserInfoHeaderFilter userInfoHeaderFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(UserInfoHeaderFilter userInfoHeaderFilter) {
        this.userInfoHeaderFilter = userInfoHeaderFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .addFilterBefore(userInfoHeaderFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_ADMIN")
                )
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }
}
```

just for example, I have changed it to have one role for each request.

**JwtFilter code:**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class UserInfoHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public static final String HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";

    private static final String NO_USER = "NO USER";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
        if (headerValue != null && headerValue.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            setAuthenticationInSecurityContext(headerValue.substring(7));
        }


        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String setAuthenticationInSecurityContext(String token) {
        try {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
            String username = jwt.getClaim("preferred_username").asString();
            List<String> roles = (List<String>) jwt.getClaim("realm_access").asMap().get("roles");

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            log.debug("User [{}] has been logged", username);

            return username;
        } catch (JWTDecodeException e) {
            log.error("Failed to decode JWT", e);
            return NO_USER;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can probably see, in this filter we are only getting roles/username from jwt and putting them in `securityContext`. So no verification of jwt is needed.

And locally everything seems to be working correctly. But integration tests are failing (I have added to restTemplate interceptor, which will add every request correct jwt token)

This is simplified test, which is using `TestRestTemplate`

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = (request, body, execution) -> {
        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", BEARER + TEST_JWT_TOKEN);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    };
    restTemplate.getRestTemplate().setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
}

@Test
void stupidTest() {
    restTemplate.execute(uri("/books"), HttpMethod.GET, req -> {
    }, res -> {
        Assertions.assertTrue(res.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
        return IOUtils.toString(res.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    });

    //Thread.sleep(10000);

    AuthorRequest payload = AuthorRequest.builder()
            .name("TEST")
            .labels(Collections.emptySet())
            .build();

    restTemplate.postForEntity(uri("/author"), payload, String.class);
}
```

It is failing when second request is sent. When debugging code, it is never entering `author` endpoint nor `filter` for second time, but when adding `Thread.sleep(1000);` between those two calls it starts working correctly.

In logs I can see

> 2023-07-21 15:45:20 5.14.0 SEVERE Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to
> handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already
> committed.] with root cause
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access
> Denied
>
> 2023-07-21 15:45:20 5.14.0 SEVERE Exception Processing
> ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Unable to handle the Spring Security
> Exception because the response is already committed.
>
> I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:61916/v1/author":
> localhost:61916 failed to respond
> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> POST request for "http://localhost:61916/v1/author": localhost:61916
> failed to respond

Which seems to be saying that second request was denied, but even though why it is working correctly, with sleep? Hmm. Removing Spring Security Configuration make test works again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems issue of parallel call between asynchrone call

```
    restTemplate.execute(uri("/books"), HttpMethod.GET, req -> {
    }, res -> {
        Assertions.assertTrue(res.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
        return IOUtils.toString(res.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    });
```

and next call which is execute in parallel

```
    restTemplate.postForEntity(uri("/author"), payload, String.class);
```

Why not use restTemplate.getForEntity the 1st time to avoid parallel call and this issue of TestRestTemplate ?

But in fact to really analyse need all the Test class, especially the initialisation of TestRestTemplate

Answer (score -2):

You can disable Spring security in your test if that's not what the test is supposed to check:

```java
@Import({DisableSpringSecurityTestConfiguration.class})
public class YourTest {

   @Test
   void testSomething() {
      // ...
   }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
  // disable Spring Security auto conf to get endpoint calls in unit tests executed
  SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
  ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class DisableSpringSecurtiyTestConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: But this is no unit tests nor component test. The point of this test is to fully test end to end flow with everything running (db, kafka etc). So in my opinion there are benefits to test flow with jwt token, especially that username is used for audit log.